# How Can I Optimize an SQL Query With Multiple Conditions and Inner Join

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I optimize the SQL query below? It takes too much time. This is used to select from a very large astronomical table (a few hundred million objects), and this query runs over 12 hours which is more than the maximum allow query time. It appears that adding more restrictions via additional conditions doesn't help at all.

Your help is much appreciated!

```
select AVG(o.zMeanPSFMagStd) into mydb.z1819 
from MeanObject as o 
join ObjectThin ot on ot.ObjID=o.ObjID 
inner join StackObjectAttributes soa on soa.objID=o.objid 
where o.zMeanPSFMag>=18 
    and o.zMeanPSFMag<19 
    and o.zQfPerfect > 0.85 
    and (ot.qualityFlag & 1) = 0 
    and (ot.qualityFlag & 2) = 0 
    and o.zMeanPSFMagErr <> -999 
    and o.zMeanPSFMagStd <> -999 
    and ot.nz > 10 and soa.zpsfMajorFWHM < 6  
    and soa.zpsfMinorFWHM/nullif(soa.zpsfMajorFWHM,0) > 0.65 
    and soa.zpsfFlux/nullif(soa.zpsfFluxErr,0)>5 
    and (ot.b>10 or ot.b<-10) 
    and (ot.raMean>0 and ot.raMean<180)
```

Comment: Is this Oracle or MySQL? `from MeanObject as o` and `(ot.qualityFlag & 1)` aren't valid in Oracle. The `& 1` syntax looks like a [MySQL bitwise AND](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-functions.html).

Comment: To tune a query we would need table and index definitions, volumes and execution plans, not to mention the DBMS vendor.